# asp.net MVC generic action handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a documentation for the OSS I am about to publish. The url is going to be like `/Documentation/{class name}` . All the documentation view are named as `{namespace}_{classname}`. Basically i wonder if there is a way to direct all requests to `/Documentation/*` to a method inside my Documentation controller so that i can do something like

```
return View({class name});
```

instead of having to make a method for each class

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS URL Rewrite ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642625/iis-url-rewrite-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that in routing.

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Docs",                                              // Route name
       "Documentation/{className}",                           // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Documentation", action = "Show", className = "" }  // Parameter defaults
 );
```

That assumes of course that you have a DocumentationController with a Show attribute.