# Classics ASP IIS 6.0 how to implement url rewrite?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2003

This is a shared hosting environment running on Windows Server 2003. I want to integrate url rewriting,so below translates:

example.com/product-name-color-ID  ===> example.com/product?id=ID

Custom 404 page technique seems easiest way for me but how can i do that?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20646973/1682881

Comment: Thanks i put the web.config file and 404.asp page to the root directory of my site. But when i write example.com/not_exists it doesn't go to the 404.asp. Instead i see "The system cannot find the file specified. " error

Comment: Even in shared hosting you usually get an option to set up an error page. Can you try it that way

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a custom 404 hack, check out [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/). It lets you use an .htaccess file (like Apache) for URL rewriting.

Comment: There's also IIRF if you don't want to pay for Helicon Ape
http://iirf.codeplex.com/